# Install ASP.NET Core 6.0 with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, multiple-versions

I currently have installed ASP.NET Core 3.1 on my computer. Now I need to install ASP.NET Core 6.0 to develop a project on ASP.NET Core 6.0 as well on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Operating System.

When I run the below code

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

It shows the following response

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dotnet-sdk-6.0 is already the newest version (6.0.101-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 153 not upgrade
```

but when I check available SDK using `dotnet --list-sdks`

it shows

```
3.1.416 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/153/sdk]
```

How can I solve this

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why can't you just install it?

Comment: Yes - just run the install ....

Comment: when I run the following code 
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0

it show following response
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dotnet-sdk-6.0 is already the newest version (6.0.101-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 153 not upgrade


but when I checked available SDK using dotnet --list-sdks

it show
3.1.416 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/153/sdk]

Comment: It looks like you installed dotnet via `snap` BEFORE you installed it via `apt-get`, my guess is both installations are incompatible with each other.  My suggestion would be to avoid using `snap` and install both SDKs via `apt-get`.  The path to `snap`'s version of dotnet will be `/snap/...`, while the `apt-get` install will be `/usr/bin/dotnet`, if you do `/usr/bin/dotnet --list-sdks` you should see 6.0 there.  Alternatively, install both SDKs via `snap`.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft .NetCore 6 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)

You Need to dowload and install it, also you can do it with Visual Studio, You can Have Both, there is no problem.

Comment: when I run 

sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
it show following response 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dotnet-sdk-6.0 is already the newest version (6.0.101-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 153 not upgrade


but when I check available SDK using 

dotnet --list-sdks

it show

3.1.416 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/153/sdk]

Comment: You use snap, before the common instalation, to avoid more problems i recommend u to unistall both sdk and reinstall those again! that should solve your problem

Comment: unistall both sdk and reinstall  worked for me

Comment: nice, si if that help to you and you can mark it as an answer apreciate it! have a nice day